# How to join two tables that have a common field in third table?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

How to join two tables that have a common field in third table?

E.g: Table A has RoleId, role description and Table B has AccessId,Access description.Table C has RoleAccessID,roleid, accessid. I need to display role description and their access description.Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this below logic for your purpose-

```
SELECT A.role_description, B.access_description 
FROM TABLE_A A
INNER JOIN TABLE_C C ON A.RoleId = C.RoleId
INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON C.AccessId = B.AccessId
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT 
          role.RoleID,
          role.Role_Description, 
          ac.AccessId, 
          ac.Access_Description
    FROM tblRole role 
    INNER JOIN tblRoleAccessInfo rac ON A.RoleId = C.RoleId
    INNER JOIN tblAccessInfo ac ON C.AccessId = B.AccessId
```